# RegEx for digits, chars and commas

Tags: regex

Please, help me to compose a regular expression to match digits, chars (case doesn't matter) and commas, but with first, last or several in a row commas invalid.
Valid string examples: "123,АВc,0aB12,3c", "ABc", "567".
Invalid string examples: "123,,456789"; ","; ",,"; ",123,456"; "123,456,".

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this works:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]+(,[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 ^([A-Za-z0-9]+,)*[A-Za-z0-9]+$
```

If can use PCRE compatible regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
[0-9A-Za-z]+(?:,[0-9A-Za-z]+)*
```

Answer (score 1):

`/^[0-9a-z]+(,[0-9a-z]+)*$/i` (not tested)

Answer (score 1):

Match some alphanumerics, then optionally groups consisting of a comma followed by some alphanumerics:

```
^[\dA-Za-z]+(,[\dA-Za-z]+)*$
```